# Does someone got stuck with "savefig" in Julia?

Tags: julia, plotly.js, savefig

I have a problem with savefig (inside PlotlyJS) that I can't know where it comes from. The code is simple, there are some scatters and a figure that show correctly:

```
using PlotlyJS

n_points = 250
x_vals = 1:n_points
example_data = rand(n_points)
constant_mean = 0.5

trace1 = scatter(; x=x_vals, y=fill(constant_mean, n_points), name="Mean χ = 0.5")
trace2 = scatter(; x=x_vals, y=example_data, name="Data χ = 0.5")

layout = Layout(; title="Simplified Example")
p = plot([trace1, trace2], layout)
```

But when I run

```
savefig(p, "Plots/net_comparative.png")
```

The REPL gets stuck. It saves something, but it is a broken file, which I interpret to mean that the process "did not complete". However, it can get stuck like this for days and never finishes. They are simple plots that my other computer saves normally. Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

Actualization: Recently, I've discovered that it works if I save it as a .html but not as a .png or .pdf.

System data:

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.9.1
Commit 147bdf428c (2023-06-07 08:27 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Windows (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
  CPU: 16 × 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12650H
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-14.0.6 (ORCJIT, alderlake)
  Threads: 1 on 16 virtual cores
Environment:
  JULIA_EDITOR = code
  JULIA_NUM_THREADS =


julia> Pkg.status()
Status `C:\Users\franc\.julia\environments\v1.9\Project.toml`
⌃ [35d6a980] ColorSchemes v3.22.0
⌃ [31c24e10] Distributions v0.25.98
  [a98d9a8b] Interpolations v0.14.7
  [caafb194] Kaleido v0.2.7
⌃ [429524aa] Optim v1.7.6
  [a03496cd] PlotlyBase v0.8.19 `https://github.com/sglyon/PlotlyBase.jl#master`
  [f0f68f2c] PlotlyJS v0.18.11
⌃ [c3e4b0f8] Pluto v0.19.27
  [2fc8631c] PlutoSliderServer v0.3.26
  [fcd29c91] QuantEcon v0.16.5
⌃ [f2b01f46] Roots v2.0.17
⌃ [2913bbd2] StatsBase v0.34.0
  [37e2e46d] LinearAlgebra
  [de0858da] Printf
  [9a3f8284] Random
Info Packages marked with ⌃ have new versions available and may be upgradable.
```

Comment: ERROR: UndefVarError: `pC_mean2` not defined

Comment: You should really make this into a self contained MWE by providing some dummy data, ideally including a case that works and a case that hangs. If you can produce this it sounds like a bug in PlotlyJS to me which would best be dealt with by filing an issue there.

Comment: @Mark thks. I've just copied a sample of my code and excluded that definition. But code itself is okay, that's not the problem.

Comment: @NilsGudat I understand. The problem is that it doesn't work for ANY plot. Doesn't matter if it is a scatter or a contour. It just gets stuck when I use savefig. I will try to open an issue in PlotlyJS. Thanks

Comment: Ah sorry I think I misread your question - you are saying the same code runs on a different machine you have so the problem isn't actually reproducible?

Comment: Right! I have another old computer that runs it perfectly, haha. Should be some kind of incompatibility between my new computer, Windows 11 and PlotlyJS.

Comment: in that case, it might be useful to add some details about your setup on the non-functional computer, e.g. Julia version, package versions etc.

Comment: and my comment was pointing at the same thing which @NilsGudat said more explicitly - I can't reproduce your problem if I can't even begin to run your code

Comment: Thanks, @Mark. I've added some information and changed the code to make it reproducible. If you find something that takes your attention, please let me know.

Comment: @FrancoRiottini thanks for that- I tried running your code - I got an error initially because of not having the Plots folder, but after that it ran okay

Comment: It's super weird. I've tried reinstalling everything. The saddest part is that the computer has only 4 months!

Comment: It works here. I have seen this if the particular computer in question either lacks a graphics library used by PlotlyJS.jl for file export or has a version installed that is broken under PlotlyJS and the code is reaching for that version.  For example, a "version hell" configuration with ImageMagick could do this with some file export routines. You could try installing ImageMagick.jl and ImageIO.jl to see if that corrects the configuration.